# Android Developers MyFirstApp - "menu cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, eclipse

I am attempting to build my first app using the [tutorial provided by android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) in Eclipse.

I've done everything is says but i get the error message..."menu cannot be resolved or is not a field". The tutorial doesn't mention anything about a menu and i'm sure i haven't done anything to it. The line it is complaining about i've marked in a comment.

```
package com.example.my.first.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);        <!--this line-->
    return true;
}
}
```

This is the main activity page the tutorial has asked me to edit is shown below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Going off advice i've found on other questions i've attempted clicking on it and to include what ever it's asking for which is "Create field 'menu' in type 'R' or "Create constant 'menu' in type 'R'. I've done both separately and every time i save the project so it rebuilds, it automatically deletes the line that was included.

For the field, this was done. - public static Object menu;
For the constant, this was done. - public static final String menu = null;

So i'm now a little stuck and would like some much needed help please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The onCreateOptionsMenu method refers to a menu that has to be in /res/menu folder and is implemented as XML. Looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" />
</menu>
```

You can copy/ paste this code, save it as activity_main.xml in your /res/menu folder (create one if you dont have one) or just delete the whole method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);        <!--this line-->
    return true;
}
```

What this does is open a menu when you hit the menu button on the device, if you delete the method, you wont have such a menu.  You can still create one if you need one.

Comment: I already have the code you mentioned in the place you mentioned...
/My First App/res/layout/menu/activity_main.xml


<code>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu> </code>

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm unsure on how to put code in to these comments.

Comment: My First App/res/layout/menu/activity_main.xml
Thats the folder for the layout. You have to have a activity_main.xml in My First App/res/menu/activity_main.xml.

If you have the code i posted in the layout folder, theres something wrong.

Comment: If i start to type out the line that the error appears on.....getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, menu). When entering the attribute menuRes, i get up to "R." but no menu is shown. Other options are available like layout, string, style but no menu.

Comment: Well, do you have a menu folder in /res?
Also, dont rely too much on Eclipses (or Netbeans) auto- completion; it sucks sometimes.

Comment: There isn't a menu folder directly in res. Only in res/layout

Comment: As i said, create one, copy the xm code from above, create new file in your new menu folder, paste code, save as activity_main.xml.

Comment: I've moved the menu folder out of layout and directly under res and everything seems to build without any errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Check and see if you are importing android.R. If so, remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put your menu.xml file in res/menu/ directory.

Comment: Should this be menu.xml or activity_main.xml as Ascorbin suggested? I have a activity_main.xml already there.

Comment: No, activity_main.xml of course. I just give an example. Then i don't see anything wrong in your code. It should work normally.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse IDE--->Package Explore in Eclipse > res > menu > main.xml or main_activity_actions files... check its name.. and put into statement inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); the name you are using in inflater statement can't be resolved or is field in your app.. so first confirm it then that what is the correct file name in menu dirctory and then use it in your statement.